# What do you call someone who puts his name on something that is not his own?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage

Like I make a drawing with my name and you go and display it as a picture on your website with your logo on it.

Answer (score 1):

You could call it [plagiarism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism).

Comment: To answer to OP question : plagiarist.

Answer (score 0):

An **usurper** is one who takes or makes use of something without right.

Examples :

> Nowadays a patent is a monopoly (an exclusive right or holding) conferred by the state on, and for, the benefit of the originator and
> not a **usurper** of an invention.
>
> Make no mistake, the only reason that
> a **usurper** would adopt another company’s legacy mark is to take the
> residual good will and divert business from the legacy brand owner. A
> few simple steps during re-branding can insure that your legacy mark
> enjoys a happy retirement

Another example is the [text](https://provimarcas.com.co/en/services/legal-proceedings/usurpation-of-industrial-property-rights/) found in the web site of a company specialized in property rights protection :

> USURPATION OF INDUSTRIAL PROPERTY RIGHTS
>
> When a third party fraudulently uses the distinctive marks or new
> creations legally protected without the authorization of the owners,
> it may be denounced before the public prosecutor’s office to
> criminally condemn the acts of **usurpation**.
>
> What is sought with this process is that the **usurper** is condemned to
> pay a fine, and in certain cases, a prison sentence of 3 to 6 years.

Comment: Not really. A usurper is taking a position of power illegally or by force.

Comment: @DoneWithThis : Napoleon was called so. But, usurpation is also a wrongful exercise of possession.

Comment: I still don't think it fits this case, nor would it be understood by most people as such. tbh, I don't have a better answer, because I only get as far as 'IP theft'

Answer (score 0):

*Appropriator* could be possible.

> someone who takes for his or her own use (especially without permission)

[https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/appropriator#:~:text=Definitions%20of%20appropriator,poacher](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/appropriator#:%7E:text=Definitions%20of%20appropriator,poacher)